# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts only on visual studio/C#

Tags: c#, mysql

```
private void createAccount(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still here");
        string usernameString = username.Text;
        string passwordString = password.Text;
        string repeatpasswordString = repeatpassword.Text;
        string emailString = email.Text;
        MySqlConnection connection;
        connectionString = "server=;uid=root;pwd=root;database=mydb;";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString); //create connection 
        connection.Open(); //connects       

        //  if (passwordString.Equals(repeatpasswordString)) { 
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
        Console.WriteLine(usernameString);
        commandString = "INSERT INTO account (username,password,email) VALUES (${username}, ${password}, ${email})";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(commandString, connection);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //}
    }
}
```

Thats my code, I can connect to my database fine with the same credentials on python. Thanks a lot!
EDIT: The error I am getting is MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

Comment: are you getting any exception? If yes please update in the question

Comment: I just copied and pasted it!

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to specify the server parameter. If you run the database locally, then you can change your line to:

```
    connectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=mydb;";
```

or

```
    connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=root;database=mydb;";
```

If you run the database not locally, you should add your server host address.

Comment: this was a mistake on the copy-pasting sorry! Still doesnt work

Comment: is the name of your db really mydb?

Answer (score -1):

If your connection string is

```
connectionString = "server=;uid=root;pwd=root;database=mydb;";
```

Then is wrong connection string. You must fill server address, for example:

```
connectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=mydb;";
```

More examples you can find [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: @SeanStayns find 5 Differenses